# Let $A_1,...,A_n$ be linearly independent n x n matrices. Let M be an invertible n x n matrix. Show that $MA_1,...,MA_n$ is also linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A_1,...,A_n$ be linearly independent  n x n matrices. Let $M$ be an invertible n x n matrix. Show that $MA_1,...,MA_n$ is also linearly independent.

I know what it means for it to be linearly independent but don't know how to show it for this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prove it by reductio ad absurdum. Assume $MA_1,\cdots , MA_n$ are not linearly independent. Then there exist $a_1,\cdots ,a_n$ (not all zero) such that

$$a_1MA_1+\cdots + a_nMA_n=M(a_1A_1+\cdots + a_nA_n)=0.$$ Now, since $M$ is invertible, we get that

$$a_1A_1+\cdots + a_nA_n=0.$$ That is, $A_1,\cdots, A_n$ are not linearly independent. This gives us a contradiction (since $a_1,\cdots ,a_n$ are not all zero).

Answer (score 2):

The multiplication
$$
 \phi \colon \operatorname{Mat}_n(K) \to \operatorname{Mat}_n(K),
 \quad A \mapsto MA
$$
is $K$-linear and bijective with inverse
$$
 \phi^{-1} \colon \operatorname{Mat}_n(K) \to \operatorname{Mat}_n(K),
 \quad A \mapsto M^{-1} A,
$$
i.e. $\phi$ is an isomorphism of $K$-vector spaces. In particular the linear independent family $(A_1, \dotsc, A_n)$ is mapped to a linear independent family, namely $(MA_1, \dotsc, MA_n)$.